# How to override facets checkbox theme and style checkboxes checked state?

Tags: theming, 9

I'm having trouble to style Drupal 9 facets checkbox in checked state. I have tried to override the theme by theme_preprocess_checkboxes with no effect.

here is my code :

```
 function mytheme_preprocess_checkboxes($variables) {

  $element = $variables['element'];
  $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'checkbox';
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', '#return_value' => 'value'));

  // Unchecked checkbox has #value of integer 0.
  if (!empty($element['#checked'])) {
      $element['#attributes']['checked'] = 'checked';
  }
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-checkbox'));

  return '<input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' /><span></span>';
}
```

I guess i'm not getting facets checkboxes with it. Any suggestions how do i style facets and override their templates.

I'm using bootstrap 3 subtheme on drupal 9

Comment: Unfortunately preprocess_checkboxes hook is depricated and will be no longer available from Drupal 10 version... so looking for the solutions. probably i need to rewrite twig temeplate but still can't find it even in facets module templates folder... :(

Comment: getting more closer to it : public static function Checkbox::preRenderCheckbox for non facets checkboxes in checked stade adds to element css class. butr still canot track the facets chekbox renedering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkboxes are created in JS, not PHP, so you won't be able to manipulate them from the backend (see `Drupal.facets.makeCheckbox` in facets/js/checkbox-widget.js for the code).

It does mean you can just use some simple JS yourself, though; for example assuming you need to append an empty span you'd, probably just need to add something like this to a custom behavior:

```
$('.facets-checkbox').after($('<span />'))
```

(that's just a minimal example, you should use `once` or a similar mechanism to make sure it isn't executed multiple times for the same element).

Comment: Thanks Clive will try this bit